# Sender address is not valid when send email Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I will make mail delivery system using PHP CodeIgniter. Email successfully submitted, but when I check my email, the sender mail is my **smtp_user**, not the real email sender.

for example: My **smtp_user** is a@gmail.com. When user send mail to me, sender mail is a@gmail.com, not user@gmail.com.

Here is my code in **email.php** :

```
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_user'] = "a@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "blablabla";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['priority'] = "1";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

And here is my controller :

```
$this->load->library('email');
$link=base_url()."verification/".$verification_code."";
$body="Thanks for joining <br> Your code verification is 
      <a href=".$link." target='_blank'>".$link."</a>";
$this->email->from($this->input->post('mails'), strtoupper($name));
$this->email->to('b@gmail.com');                        
$this->email->subject('New account registration');
$this->email->message($body);
$this->email->send());
```

What's wrong with my **config email**?

but if I using smtp_host with mandrillapp, I did'nt see the problem like above.

Comment: Try this with smtp host `'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',`

Comment: it still doesn't work @wolfgang1983

Comment: Set attributes for from and fromname